# Is there to create a new instance of a singleton service for only one module

Tags: angular

I have a singleton service being shared across all modules. But for one the modules i want it to have it’s own instance of the service and not use the shared singleton instance. Is it possible to achieve in Angular?

Also, the service requiring it’s own instance of the service is being used inside a module using the shared singleton instance of the service.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible.

For that particular module, add the following code:

```
{provide: SomeService, useClass: SomeService}
```

to the **providers array** in module file.

For example like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // ...
  ],
  imports: [
    // ...
  ],
  exports: [
    // ...
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: SomeService, useClass: SomeService}
  ]
})
```

By doing this, any component in this module will receive a new instance of **SomeService** instead of using the shared singleton instance.

Do not add **SomeService** to the **imports** **array** of that module, as it will cause a conflict."

Comment: And probably still have `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` on the `SomeService`

Comment: yes, in `SomeService`  you still need to have `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })`

Comment: It doesn’t work in case where the module requiring it’s own instance is being used in a module using the singleton shared service